# how can i remove notifications and alerts from browser? selenium python 2.7.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am trying to submit information in a webpage, but selenium throws this error:

> UnexpectedAlertPresentException: Alert Text: This page is asking you
>   to confirm that you want to leave - data you have entered may not be
>   saved. ,
>   >

It's not a leave notification; here is a pic of the notification -

[image].

If I click in never show this notification again, my action doesn't get saved; is there a way to save it or disable all notifications?

**edit:** I'm using firefox.

Comment: yes im using firefox.

Answer (score 24):

You can disable the browser notifications, using chrome options. Sample code below:

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications" : 2}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Comment: For me when a new page was loaded, element that i wanted was unclickable by an add. After implementing your solution, the add is still loaded by it is ignored by the scraper and i no longer get the error " element unclickable at point (xxx)"

Comment: This doesn't solve it for my 'are you sure you want to leave the page' pop-up, in Chrome 74.

Answer (score 11):

With the latest version of Firefox the above preferences didn't work.

Below is the solution which disable notifications using Firefox object

```
_browser_profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
_browser_profile.set_preference("dom.webnotifications.enabled", False)
webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=_browser_profile)
```

Disable notifications when using Remote Object:
`webdriver.Remote(desired_capabilities=_desired_caps, command_executor=_url,  options=_custom_options, browser_profile=_browser_profile)`

selenium==3.11.0

Answer (score 2):

Usually with browser settings like this, any changes you make are going to get throws away the next time Selenium starts up a new browser instance.

Are you using a dedicated Firefox profile to run your selenium tests? If so, in that Firefox profile, set this setting to what you want and then close the browser. That should properly save it for its next use. You will need to tell Selenium to use this profile though, thats done by SetCapabilities when you start the driver session.

Comment: Profile management is built into Firefox, start Firefox from a run command as 'firefox -p' to go into the manager. I typically have a dedicated Webdriver instance. I will also install Firebug in it, to make debugging easier. There's guides online, and plenty of code examples on stackoverflow on setting capabilities (thats how I learned).

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
options = Options()
options.set_preference("dom.webnotifications.enabled", False)
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options)
```

Answer (score 1):

For Google Chrome and v3 of Selenium you may receive "DeprecationWarning: use options instead of chrome_options", so you will want to do the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--disable-notifications')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)
```

Note: I am using webdriver-manager, but this also works with specifying the executable_path.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is an improvement on [TH Todorov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34371491/5771148) code snippet, based on what is working as of Chrome (Version 80.0.3987.163).

lk = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "chromedriver",) --> in this line you provide the link to the chromedriver, which you can download from [chromedrive link](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home)

```
import os

from selenium import webdriver

lk = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "chromedriver",)
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications" : 2}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(lk, options=chrome_options)
```