# How do you disable the are you sure you want to leave this page alert?

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

How do you disable the are you sure you want to leave this page alert when running selenium in chrome?

Comment: can you  please try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32953498/how-can-i-remove-notifications-and-alerts-from-browser-selenium-python-2-7-7

Comment: that's not working for me

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you intend to leave the page, why not accept the alert?

```
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```