# Catch the closing event of the chrome browser using chrome driver

Tags: vb.net, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I am doing the automation in an application for some web pages in the vb.net using the chrome driver.

During the application operation here is a chance that chrome may close before completion of automation process (user may close or chrome may crash).

Now my requirement is that if the chrome is closed by the user while automation is running, the application needs to know that a close event in chrome is raised by the user and the application needs give a Yes/No message with the custom text to confirm the action of the user.

I searched this for some time on the internet and found nothing. Please provide the way to catch the closing event of the chrome browser in vb.net using the chrome driver.

Comment: There is nothing in the webdriver spec (https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/) about some sort of "browser closing" event.
You can only get what's happening in the browser itself, (like alerts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32953498/how-can-i-remove-notifications-and-alerts-from-browser-selenium-python-2-7-7).
Selenium comes with an EventFiringWebDriver class but it's just a wrapper on its own events, not a listener on events coming from the browser. What you could do though is inject some script on pages when they are loaded to add your checks in the browser execution context.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I quite understand the question, but can you use the `window.onbeforeunload` approach?

e.g. [See W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onbeforeunload.asp)

Comment: Also see this [code project](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/58835/Window-Close-Event-of-Browser).

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        //your code here
    };
});
```