# Unable to handle Chrome notifications in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Try to block/cross the popup, see the image:[image]

My Code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.facebook.com/')
#More codes between (useless for this question)
alertObj = driver.switch_to.alert
alertObj.dismiss
```

Gave me the error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoAlertPresentException: Message: no such
>   alert

Full Message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "D:\python_projects\facebook\page\index.py", line 25,
>   in < module>
>       alertObj = driver.switch_to.alert   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\switch_to.py",
>   lin e 55, in alert
>       alert.text   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\alert.py", line
>   69 , in text
>       return self.driver.execute(Command.GET_ALERT_TEXT)["value"]   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   lin e 320, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py",
>   line 242, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.NoAlertPresentException: Message: no such
>   alert

Comment: @Andersson I am not able to match my question with the link you povided....

Comment: What do you mean by *"match my answer"*? What is your *answer*?

Comment: Sorry, I mean "match my question", meanwhile I got an alternative answer for this at https://stackoverflow.com/a/34371491/10303845 but what if I want to handle all the alerts??

Comment: This is not an alert. Alert is popup created by calling JavaScript `alert()` function. Alert contains one button only. This popup is Chrome notification and it should be handled differently...