# RSelenium: block a site from showing notifications in Chrome

Tags: r, selenium, google-chrome, rselenium

[image]

I am using RSelenium and I want to set Chrome to block notifications by default. The challenge is that I have multiple docker containers running at the same time, so the solution has to scale. How can this be done programmatically?

I get from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32953498/how-can-i-remove-notifications-and-alerts-from-browser-selenium-python-2-7-7/32954722) that it could be done in python, but the syntax does not translate to R.

Here's my code so far:

```
library(RSelenium)

driver<- rsDriver(port = 4445L, browser = 'chrome')
remDr <- driver[["client"]]
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("https://www.blendernation.com/")
```

Comment: You could click on "block" within selenium and then I'm assuming that choice will be remembered for your entire session. You'd probably need to re-click when you start a new one though.

Comment: Thanks for your input @A.Grothendieck . Indeed that could be an option for one time executions. I am looking for a method that could scale over multiple docker containers

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follows:

```
remDr$navigate(URL)
```

## here you see notification question

```
remDr$sendKeysToActiveElement(list(key = "escape"))
```

Notification dialog is still visible but now the browser responds to UI commands (like sendkeys etc). So effectively you can proceed further.