# Python + Selenium + Chromium Disable notifications?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Ive been trying to figure out how to disable the notification pop ups when I visit certain websites with selenium. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how can i remove notifications and alerts from browser? selenium python 2.7.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32953498/how-can-i-remove-notifications-and-alerts-from-browser-selenium-python-2-7-7)